# Display messages using JavaScript

Tags: django

I wonder if there is JS snippet/library for displaying messages from Django messages framework, when CookieStorage is used.

It would be awesome for caching purposes, because it would be possible to cache whole views, even if they displays messages.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to leverage something from this article on integrating OS X "growl" style notifications via the messages framework: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2007/12/add-growl-notifications-to-your-django-apps.ars